# How to save submitted form image field before clean method in Form Wizard (Django 1.2)

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I get "This field is required" error for image field on submitting a form in **Form Wizard**.

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label = _("Username*"),
        max_length = 30,
        widget = forms.TextInput()
    )
    image = forms.ImageField(label = _("Profile picture*"), required=True)
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('name','gender','birth_date',)
```

This is my last form in form wizard. On submitting this form I got username and other fields in clean method but not the image. Is there a way to save image before validation of this form to avoid "This field is required" error?

Comment: you mean, you want to exclude the field "image" from validation ?

Comment: I want to validate it but this field is empty on submitting of form, although the uploaded file is present in request.FILES . Also in "self.data" in "clean" method of this form image field is not present. @Paulo can you tell me the method where form is submitted before validation in Form wizard?

Comment: In request.FILES <MultiValueDict: {u'2-image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: image1.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>. But in request.POST "image" field is not present. I wanted to do something like :                                                              "SignupForm(request.POST, request.FILES)", so that I can validated image field manually.

Comment: soo i did more reading on this, and found out that the reason why u can't use a file ( image ) is because its not supported, so my solution to you is to read this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7439 and edit the django.contrib.formtools app or just copy and paste formtools in your project and change the imports to yourproject.formtools , just apply the patch provided in the link and it should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload your images through Form Wizard you should change the file "django/contrib/formtools/wizard.py". These changes are mentioned in this Ticket [code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7439](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/7439/multipart_form_as_last_in_formwizard.diff). If you dont want to change djnago code then simply copy "formtools" folder into your apps then make changes there and instead of using:

```
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard import FormWizard
```

use:

```
from formtools.wizard import FormWizard
```

Also set enctype="multipart/form-data" of your template form.